# How can I programatically focus on an element (tab into it)?

Tags: jquery

I need to make elements of a page accessible with keyboard so users can tab through the page. I managed this bit, but I need as well to be able to programatically tab into certain anchor elements (anchor tag `<a></a>`).

`$('#elementid').focus()` doesn't do the trick; it doesn't give the same effect as using the keyboard tab to reach the element (no dotted border around the element for instance in firefox/ie).

Do you know how I can do this, how can I simulate tabbing into an elements with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Focusing on a DOM element is not the same as moving the caret around it. I can't see a use case for what you're asking, though I suppose it's an interesting enough question.

Comment: well, the use case is quiet peculiar. It's to make a UI accessible (section 508), at some points, I need to have some control about where to tab into next (instead of letting the browser decide)

Comment: You can control tab order, but you can't control the visible caret for programmatic focusing. These are two very different things.

Comment: I tried the tabindex approach, but it seems like the tab indexes are cached when the page is loaded, while I need to tab into elements that are dynamically inserted at some point to the DOM. So even though I gave those elements a tabindex lower than the next item, chrome and firefox would still ignore it and iterate with the original tabindex order.

Comment: Interesting! We're venturing quite far from your original question now...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you may not.

`.focus` is the proper way to gain keyboard focus on input elements, but you won't be able to focus on arbitrary nodes.

The "dotted border" is simply a UI mechanism used by browsers for a visual cue when you are using the TAB key to iterate through nodes: it has no semantic value and no relevance to a programmatic solution.

If you wish to style your elements, use CSS.

---

From your comments, it sounds like maybe you actually meant to ask [how to manipulate the tab order](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.1).

Comment: How does it matter? Is it impolite to comment on an old topic/answer?